# How can I stop OpenOffice from changing the page size?

Tags: printing, printer, openoffice-writer

I am designing a book in OpenOffice Writer. The book is 6x9, and that needs to be the page size -- the logical page size, if you will. But while working on it, I need to print pages on 8.5x11 paper, because that's what I have. (The published book will be printed by a printing company.)

Every time I try to print a page, OpenOffice changes the printer page size to Envelope C5. That means the edge of my page gets cropped off, because my printer can't handle the tiny margins it would take to print a 6x9 page on a C5 envelope.

How can I make OpenOffice print a 6x9 logical page on an 8.5x11 physical page without going into printer properties every single time I want to print a page, and without changing the logical page size to something other than 6x9?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to define different page styles. AFAIK, OOo doesn't know something like "logical page size". So, the best bet is to switch between physical page sizes using page styles. By defining the main matter margins, you can make sure that changing the page size doesn't affect page breaks.

Another option may be to manually select the printer media size in the printing dialog. But it depends on the printer driver if this works.

Finally, you may overcome OOo's limitations by creating a PDF with a certain size and resize it using PDF tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template for what document parameters you want to load as a default.

Found this option, hope it helps.

It was in the help section of the OpenOffice program itself.

Look up "Changing the Default Template" in Help".